# Error: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessBuildingException, How fix it?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jetty

I have a problem with my project. When i `mvn jetty:run`then occur a following error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creati ng bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/ userservice-servlet.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessBuildingException:
>   Could not loc ate field nor getter method for property named
>   [edu.java.spring.service.user.mod el.User#username]

Here file userservice-servlet.xml

```
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd ">
    <context:component-scan base-package="edu.java.spring.service.user.controller"></context:component-scan>
    <context:component-scan base-package="edu.java.spring.service.user.dao"></context:component-scan>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>

        </property>
        <property name="mappingLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:User.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="packagesToScan" value="edu.java.spring.service.user.model" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:derby:D:\PROJECTSPRING\userdb;create=true" />
        <property name="username" value="" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Here file User.java

```
package edu.java.spring.service.user.model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
@Entity
//@Table(name = "user",uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames="username")})
public class User {
//  @Column(name = "gender", nullable = false)
//  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
//  @Id
//  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
//  @Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
//  @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    public String getPassWord() {
        return passWord;
    }
    public void setPassWord(String passWord) {
        this.passWord = passWord;
    }
//  @Column(name = "birthday", nullable = false)
    public Date getBirthDay() {
        return birthDay;
    }

    public void setBirthDay(Date birthDay) {
        this.birthDay = birthDay;
    }
//  @Column(name="age", nullable = false)
    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    private String userName;
    private String passWord;
    private Date birthDay;
    private Integer age;
    private Gender gender;


}
```

Here file User.hbm.xml

```
?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="edu.java.spring.service.user.model.User" table="user">
        <id name="username" column="username"/>
        <property name="password" column="password"/>
        <property name="birthday" type="date" column="birthday"/>
        <property name="age" type="number" column="age"/>
        <property name="gender" column="gender" />

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Please, add `User.hbm.xml` and a full stack trace.

Comment: @v.ladynev i have edit file User.hbm.xml on my post

Answer (score 1):

Your User.hbm.xml file is specifying property username (all lowecase) and your User class has a userName property (camel case). Hibernate is expecting to find getUsername() and setUsername() methods instead of getUserName() and setUserName()